# Error accessing Room Database using RxJava, with Use Cases and Clean Architecure

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java, rx-java2, clean-architecture

I'm building an app using clean architecture.
I'm getting an error when calling an use case from my ViewModel that needs to run a query on my Room Database, telling me I'm accessing it in the main thread.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot access database on the main thread since it may potentially lock the UI for a long period of time.
    at android.arch.persistence.room.RoomDatabase.assertNotMainThread(RoomDatabase.java:204)
    at android.arch.persistence.room.RoomDatabase.query(RoomDatabase.java:232)
    at com.something.data.db.PatientDAO_Impl.getAllPatients(PatientDAO_Impl.java:229)
    at com.something.data.repositories.dataSource.PatientDataStoreFactory.create(PatientDataStoreFactory.kt:18)
    at com.something.data.repositories.PatientRepositoryImplementation.getPatient(PatientRepositoryImplementation.kt:97)
    at com.something.domain.useCases.GetPatientUseCase.execute(GetPatientUseCase.kt:10)
    at com.something.some_thing.searchForm.SearchFormViewModel.getPatientFromDb(SearchFormViewModel.kt:49)
    at com.something.some_thing.searchForm.SearchFormFragment.onCreateView(SearchFormFragment.kt:99)
    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2439)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1460)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1784)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1852)
    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:802)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2625)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2411)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2366)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2273)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:3273)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:3229)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentController.java:201)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:620)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:178)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1334)
    at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:7057)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2819)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2931) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1620) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:173) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6698) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:782)
```

Here is some code

My ViewModel call:

```
fun getPatient(){
    val disposable = getPatientUseCase.execute()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(this::getPatientSuccess, this::onError)
    compositeDisposable.add(disposable)
}
```

My Use Case:

```
class GetPatientUseCase(private val patientRepository: PatientRepository){

fun execute(): Single<Patient> {
    return patientRepository.getPatient()
}
```

My repository method implementation

```
override fun getPatient(): Single<Patient> {
    val patientDataStore = PatientDataStoreFactory().create()
    return patientDataStore.patient()
}
```

This is where the crash happens, in My PatientDataStoreFactory, when running db.patientDAO().getAllPatients().isNotEmpty():

```
@Singleton
class PatientDataStoreFactory {

    private val db = DaggerWrapper.getInstance().database()

    fun create(): PatientDataStore {

        return if (db.patientDAO().getAllPatients().isNotEmpty()){
            LocalPatientDataStore()
        } else {
            CloudPatientDataStore()
        }
    }
}
```

In my ViewModel I'm subscribing the use case execution so I dont understand this crash... 
Any ideas?

Comment: I bet on `db.patientDAO().getAllPatients().isNotEmpty()` of course it should be in stack trace which you didn't provide

Comment: @Selvin thanks for your answer, yeah I didn't upload the whole stacktrace but I mentioned where the error happens in the label before the code sample!

Comment: ok i didn't noice since I focus on code ... but it obvious `db.patientDAO().getAllPatients()` is prolly implemented to return `List<Patient>` so it: does *access database on the main thread* ...

Comment: Hm, but I execute the use case in the view model subscribing to a new thread, shouldn't it run all processes off the main thread? Edit: Added whole stacktrace

Comment: room also allows to execute your query on main thread but you need to enable it.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is here: `db.patientDAO().getAllPatients()`. You are calling `getAllPatients()` on the UI Thread. You should wrap in in the `Single` and subscribe on `Schedulers.io()`.

One of the possible solutions is to rewrite the following code:

```
val patientDataStore = PatientDataStoreFactory().create()
return patientDataStore.patient()
```

to something like this:

```
return Single.fromCallable { PatientDataStoreFactory().create() }
             .flatMap { store -> store.patient() }
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, that is a way to make it work without a doubt. But why am I calling getAllPatients in the main thread?
In the first sample code, I'm executing my use case and subscribing to Schedulers.io(), so all the processes running from there on should be executed off the main thread right?

Comment: No, the `getPatient()` is not executed on the IO thread. It is executed on the main thread, but returns `Single` - and this `Single` will be subscribed on the IO thread.